# Cakephp Upload Plugin 2.0 how do I store the name of a file without the extension?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using the Upload Plugin 2.0 ( https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload ) and I'm having a little trouble with populating the name field.

My form has a hidden input field for the name field.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Image', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Image'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('animal_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('attachment', array('type' => 'file'));
        echo $this->Form->input('dir', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('type', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('size', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('active', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

And I'm using the fields behavior in the maodel's $actAs array:

```
'fields' => array(
    'dir' => 'dir',
    'name' => 'name',
),
```

The documentation recommends creating the "name" field, but as it isn't being populated automatically like the size/type field I have to be missing something. I just want it to be the name of the file without the extension at the end (i.e jpg, .gif).

Comment: Try https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage its doing all of that more or less automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
public function add(){

   //...
   $path = $this->request->data['Image']['name'];
   $file_info = pathinfo($path);
   if(isset($file_info['filename'])){
      $this->request->data['Image']['name'] = $file_info['filename'];
   }
   //....
}
```

Comment: I added it to my model and saved the `$file_info['basename']` too.